# Strong convergence of multiplication operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

I am looking for a necessary and sufficient condition for a sequence of multiplication operators $T^{(k)}$ to converge to zero strongly. (i.e. $\forall x \in \mathcal{H} \quad ||T^{(k)}x - 0|| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$)

Here $T^{(k)}$ is the operator $$T^{(k)}: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$$ given by coordinate-wise multiplication, i.e.  $$T^{(k)}\left( \underline{x} \right) = (t^{k}_nx_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$

where $(t^{k}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence for each $k$.

I suppose it is obvious that it is necessary that $|t^{k}_n| \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$  for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but since $(t^{k}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^\infty$ I think this is also sufficient because we have that

$$
\sum|x_n|^2|t^{(k)}_n|^2 \le (\sup{|t^{(k)}_n|})^2\sum|x|^2 \to 0 \text{  as } k\to\infty 
$$
since
$$
\sum|x|^2 < \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \sup{|t^{(k)}_n|} \to 0 \text{ as } k\to \infty
$$

I am wondering whether this reasoning is correct or whether I have misunderstood something, because I am looking at a much more involved exposition that tries to achieve a necessary and sufficient condition but makes use of dominated convergence to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your necessary condition is that for each $n$, $t^k_n \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ (pointwise convergence).  This is **not the same** as having $\sup_n |t_n^k| \to 0$ (uniform convergence).  For instance, consider $t_n^k = n$ for $k=n$ and $t_n^k = 0$ for $k \ne n$; we have $t_n^k \to 0$ for each $n$, but $\sup_n |t_n^k| = k \to \infty$.  And indeed, the corresponding operators $T^{(k)}$ do not converge strongly (consider $x_n = 1/n$).